# What is the planning coordinate frame of moveit for PR2 (Python)

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it base_link or odom_combined? How do I check that and how do I set a specific planning frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323181/what-is-the-planning-coordinate-frame-of-moveit-for-pr2-(python)/) by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2019-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just learned to check it, it is odom_combined by the way.

```
print("============ Reference frame: ", group.get_planning_frame())
```

---

Originally posted by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) with karma: 137 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0